# How can I solve exactly in merge conflicts git

Tags: git

I read topic  [How to resolve merge conflicts in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/fix-merge-conflicts-in-git) 
but I don't know exactly how i can rolve my problem.

```
$ git fetch master 
$ git pull origin master 
From https://github.com/BruceleeThanh/StudentManager 
* branch                       master        ->      FETCH_HEAD 
Updating : 43726eb......7c5fe6a 
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge :

BusinessLogic/UserBO.cs 
SchoolManager/Entity/UserEN.cs 

Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge .
Aborting
```

Help me. Please !

Comment: You should either `git-commit` your changes or [`git-stash`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you any `local` changes those were not `committed` then you have to `commit` them first or `stash` them.

```
git stash clear // clear previous stashes
git stash // save the local changes
git pull origin master // pull the branch
git stash apply // apply the local changes
```

After that if you have any `conflict`s then resolve them and the `commit` again.

Answer (score 1):

```
git stash
git pull origin master
git stash apply
```

still if you get conflicts then find them using

```
git diff
```

and fix them manually.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the files to be saved in your origin then,

```
git add filename
git commit -m "file commit"
git push origin
```

OR 
If you dont want the files on your branch then,

```
git checkout filename
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to act.

The other solutions are right.

Other way is to create a branch where to save your local changes. Then, you will decide what to do with them.

First create the branch and checkout to it:

```
git checkout -b myTempBranch
```

Second you add and commit the changes (In your case 2 files):

```
git add BusinessLogic/UserBO.cs SchoolManager/Entity/UserEN.cs
git commit -m "Changes to review after pulling"
```

Finally, you checkout master and pull

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master
```